# how to retrieve data using bundle object in android

Tags: android

In my android app, there is one functionality Login with google plus. I have done successfully. but I want to display that data like username, email in textview in next activity. I have already done these things using intent put extra tag and retrieve into next activity. i got error which is bundle null reference. here I attached error log. Thanks in advance.

```
 Googleplus.java
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        final GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getGivenName());

        String personName = acct.getGivenName();
        String personLastName = acct.getFamilyName();
        String email = acct.getEmail();

        Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email + ", lastname: " + personLastName);

        loginButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtDisplayText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        app_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtFooterText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        digitsButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        activity_choose_login_account.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.scree);
        Intent ii = new Intent(ChooseLoginAccountActivity.this, GoogleplusActivity.class);
        ii.putExtra(PROFILE_USERNAME, acct.getGivenName());
        ii.putExtra(PROFILE_USERLASTNAME, acct.getFamilyName());
        ii.putExtra(PROFILE_EMAIL_GOOGLE, acct.getEmail());
        startActivity(ii);
   }
 }
```

here is my retriveuserinfo.java

```
create method for retrieve bundle

private String returnValueFromBundles(String key) {
    Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String returnedValue = inBundle.get(key).toString();
    return returnedValue;
}

//here get value from chooseloginactivity.java
String profilename = returnValueFromBundles(ChooseLoginAccountActivity.PROFILE_USERNAME);
    String profilelastname = returnValueFromBundles(ChooseLoginAccountActivity.PROFILE_USERLASTNAME);
    String profileemail = returnValueFromBundles(ChooseLoginAccountActivity.PROFILE_EMAIL_GOOGLE);

    //textview findviewbyid
    txtFirstName =(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.txtFirstName);
    txtLastName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtLastName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

    //set bundle value in textview for displaying
    txtFirstName.setText(profilename);
    txtLastName.setText(profilelastname);
    txtEmail.setText(profileemail);
```

but i got error [image: null object reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the value from Intent like because you have set the value in intent you have not set the bundle so you have to get the value explained below

```
String profilename=getIntent().getStringExtra((PROFILE_USERNAME);
String profle=getIntent().getStringExtra((PROFILE_USERLASTNAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should safe check if there is a value with that key to avoid nullpointer exception.

Modify your `returnValueFromBundles` like this

```
private String returnValueFromBundles(String key) {
String returnedValue="";    
if(!getIntent().getExtras().getString(key).equals(null))
{
    returnedValue = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key).toString();
}
return returnedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your data in intent so look at your code.
You should use bundle this way.. check it and edit your code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("KEY", value);  
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);

//Fire the second activity
startActivity(i);
```

}

In your second activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String value = bundle.getString("KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your values into the Bundle like this

```
    Intent ii = new Intent(ChooseLoginAccountActivity.this, GoogleplusActivity.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString(PROFILE_USERNAME, acct.getGivenName());
    b.putString(PROFILE_USERLASTNAME, acct.getFamilyName());
    b.putString(PROFILE_EMAIL_GOOGLE, acct.getEmail());
    ii.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(ii);
```

Just change your code like above.